# When to use Firebase transactions or not

Tags: firebase, web, transactions, firebase-realtime-database, atomic

Is it necessary to use the [Save data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) Technic if a value only increases?. In the example Firebase doc [social blogging app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) the `starCount` can go upp or down so it´s logical to use the Transaction Technic right. But if value only increases I suppose the Transaction Technic is not needed right? or? 
 Multiple users at the same time increasing a value right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: 17th, Aug 2021**

Now it's also possible to solve this problem without the use of a transaction. We can simply increment a value using:

```
rootRef.child("score").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

And for decremenet, the following line of code is required:

```
rootRef.child("score").setValue(ServerValue.increment(-1));
```

---

The counter can grow up or down, which means that a user can click on the counter to increase the value, but can also decrease the value if he clicks again. When we use transactions, we don't use only to increase or decrease a counter, we use if know that in our app is a possibility that two users can make the same action at the same time. If we don't use transactions, the counter can be increased/decreased only by one, instead of two times, if two users take the action at the same time.

If we use transactions, both actions will take place in different threads of execution, so there is no way in which a counter can be increased/decreased only once, even both users take the same action at the same time.

In conclusion, use transactions every time you think that is a possibility that two or more users can change the same value in your Firebase database at the same time.

Comment: Thanks but I talk about a counter that will never decrease, it can only go up.

Comment: Doesn't matter if only increase or only decrease. If only one user is using that counter than you don't need transactions. If two or more users can use the same counter in the same time, than you need transactions to avoid errors.

Comment: @ErikHellberg it's not how the data changes per se, but that it changes relative to the previous value. Since checking the value and setting a new value are independent actions, you need a transaction to ensure that it doesn't change to something else in the interim.

Comment: I understand now thanks. before increasing it I must pull it and check what current value Is and then +1. Of course a transaction is needed. Firebase take some getting use to.. :)