# firebase add value to existing node

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

let say I have a Int value in under user as 5, and I want add additional value on top of existing value. Do I retrieve the previous value and add it in Xcode then upload the new value or is there a function I can call to make it easier? Below is the value I want to add

```
guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let points = 5
        let reward = [uid : points]
```

Comment: By using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), you can update a value like you wanted (adding an integer).

Comment: If there's anyone else planning to use transaction, only use it when you have the possibility of 2 or more users accessing the same value. This thread will explain reason why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464889/when-to-use-firebase-transactions-or-not